# unable to install XML::Twig with Perl 5.008003

Tags: perl, xml-twig

I have perl version 5.008003 on my machine. I am trying to install XML::Twig using CPAN but it is failing with following errors. Can anyone help.

```
t/xmlxpath_22name_select............ok
t/xmlxpath_23func...................cannot use XML::Twig::XPath: neither XML::XP
athEngine 0.09+ nor XML::XPath are available
t/xmlxpath_23func...................ok
t/xmlxpath_24namespaces.............cannot use XML::Twig::XPath: neither XML::XP
athEngine 0.09+ nor XML::XPath are available
t/xmlxpath_24namespaces.............ok
t/xmlxpath_25scope..................cannot use XML::Twig::XPath: neither XML::XP
athEngine 0.09+ nor XML::XPath are available
t/xmlxpath_25scope..................ok
t/xmlxpath_26predicate..............cannot use XML::Twig::XPath: neither XML::XP
athEngine 0.09+ nor XML::XPath are available
t/xmlxpath_26predicate..............ok
t/xmlxpath_28ancestor2..............cannot use XML::Twig::XPath: neither XML::XP
athEngine 0.09+ nor XML::XPath are available
t/xmlxpath_28ancestor2..............ok
t/xmlxpath_29desc_with_predicate....cannot use XML::Twig::XPath: neither XML::XP
athEngine 0.09+ nor XML::XPath are available
t/xmlxpath_29desc_with_predicate....ok
t/xmlxpath_30lang...................cannot use XML::Twig::XPath: neither XML::XP
athEngine 0.09+ nor XML::XPath are available
t/xmlxpath_30lang...................ok
t/xmlxpath_additional...............cannot use XML::Twig::XPath: neither XML::XP
athEngine 0.09+ nor XML::XPath are available
t/xmlxpath_additional...............ok
t/xmlxpath_nav......................cannot use XML::Twig::XPath: neither XML::XP
athEngine 0.09+ nor XML::XPath are available
t/xmlxpath_nav......................ok
t/xmlxpath_test1....................cannot use XML::Twig::XPath: neither XML::XP
athEngine 0.09+ nor XML::XPath are available
t/xmlxpath_test1....................ok
t/xmlxpath_test_twig_roots..........cannot use XML::Twig::XPath: neither XML::XP
athEngine 0.09+ nor XML::XPath are available
t/xmlxpath_test_twig_roots..........ok
t/xmlxpath_test_with_handlers.......cannot use XML::Twig::XPath: neither XML::XP
athEngine 0.09+ nor XML::XPath are available
t/xmlxpath_test_with_handlers.......ok
t/xmlxpath_xpath_cond...............cannot use XML::Twig::XPath: neither XML::XP
athEngine 0.09+ nor XML::XPath are available
t/xmlxpath_xpath_cond...............ok
t/zz_dump_config....................

Configuration:

perl: 5.008003
OS: MSWin32 - MSWin32
required
  XML::Parser              :             2.34
'xmlwf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Use of uninitialized value in sprintf at t/zz_dump_config.t line 113.
  expat                    : <no version information found>
Strongly Recommended
  Scalar::Util             :             1.13 (for improved memory management)
  Encode                   :             1.99 (for encoding conversions)
Modules providing additional features
  XML::XPathEngine         :  <not available> (to use XML::Twig::XPath)
  XML::XPath               :  <not available> (to use XML::Twig::XPath if Tree::
XPathEngine not available)
  LWP                      :             5.75 (for the parseurl method)
  HTML::TreeBuilder        :             3.13 (to use parse_html and parsefile_h
tml)
  HTML::Entities::Numbered :  <not available> (to allow parsing of HTML containi
ng named entities)
  HTML::Tidy               :  <not available> (to use parse_html and parsefile_h
tml with the use_tidy option)
  HTML::Entities           :             1.27 (for the html_encode filter)
  Tie::IxHash              :  <not available> (for the keep_atts_order option)
  Text::Wrap               :       2001.09291 (to use the "wrapped" option for p
retty_print)
Modules used only by the auto tests
  Test                     :             1.24
  Test::Pod                :  <not available>
  XML::Simple              :             2.09
  XML::Handler::YAWriter   :  <not available>
  XML::SAX::Writer         :  <not available>
  XML::Filter::BufferText  :             1.01
  IO::Scalar               :  <not available>


Please add this information to bug reports (you can run t\zz_dump_config.t to ge
t it)

if you are upgrading the module from a previous version, make sure you read the
Changes file for bug fixes, new features and the occasional COMPATIBILITY WARNIN
G

t/zz_dump_config....................ok
Failed Test   Stat Wstat Total Fail  Failed  List of Failed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
t/test_3_36.t               67    1   1.49%  43
Failed 1/96 test scripts, 98.96% okay. 1/2374 subtests failed, 99.96% okay.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\WINNT\system32\cmd.exe' : return code '0xff'
Stop.
  NMAKE test -- NOT OK
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force

cpan>
```

All my environments has this version of perl so I cannot upgrade to latest versions. I got to fix the issue on this version only.

Thanks,

Comment: seems like you need to install XML::XPath. install it manually or setup your cpan to automatically follow the dependencies.

Comment: This is off-topic as it does not relate directly to programming; it belongs on superuser.com.

Comment: One of the test failed. You didn't show the test that failed. All the tests you showed were ok. Show the output for `t/test_3_36.t`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the summary of the tests, the failing one appears to be test 43 in t/test_3_36.t. If you look at it, it tests how HTML::TreeBuilder deals with `&Amp;` (note the upper case A) when parsing HTML. Depending on the version of HTML::TreeBuilder, `&Amp`; may be processed as `&amp;`, the entity for `&`. It appears that in the version installed on your machine (3.13), it is processed (correctly) as the literal `&Amp;`, which the test did not expect.

HTML::TreeBuilder is used when using XML::Twig to parse HTML. You can also use HTML::Tidy (you will need to install it) instead.

Whether this problem is important enough for you to not install the module, I don't know, You'll have to apply your best judgement.

As ikegami mentioned, the output you gave in your question is not optimal. There was no need to copy all the warnings (there are lots of them, and I could probably display fewer of them, but since I hope they incite users to install XML::XPathEngine I'll leave the output as is).

Comment: Applicable missing: In the CPAN shell, run `force install XML::Twig` to ignore the test failure and install the module anyway.